# jQuery setting height, width dynamically

Tags: jquery

I need to change height and width of a <div> using jQuery

I tried following code

```
jQuery('#chart_popup').css('height','600px');
jQuery('#chart_popup').css('width','450px');
```

I need this to be done in one statement, any suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in one hit like this...

```
jQuery('#chart_popup').css({height: "600px", width: "450px"});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
jQuery('#chart_popup').css( {width : '30px', height : '10px'} )
```